# Unsure how this progression is in D

Tags: theory

This is for Deal by Grateful Dead.
The progression is
A - C# - F#m - E - D - Ddim - A - F# - B7 - D

I’m trying to play A mixolydian and the C# completely throws me off because G# and F of that triad are not notes of Mixolydian.
I also don’t understand how E could be major if E is the minor II chord in the key of D. Similarly

Comment: Similarly what? Did you post only half the question you meant? Please edit it so that it ends with a whole sentence and we can be confident that everything you wanted to say is there. (There should be little links under the text of your question, one of them being "Edit".)

Comment: While we're waiting for the rest of the question: why are you trying to play A mixolydian?   What gives you the impression that one scale SHOULD fit a whole song, or part of a song?

Comment: Asked under false premises - it's in A, not D.

Comment: @Tim If I understand the asker right, he says that it's in A mixolydian, which is a mode od D major. I'm not familiar with the song and don't know if that's true or not. When I tried to find a sheet for it, the only I found was [this](https://musescore.com/user/32289041/scores/7815008) and there's indeed a signature of two sharps, though I'm not sure how trustworthy it is when as soon as the second bar I see that F that very much looks like it should be E# if the chord is C#. So is this in A mixolydian or is it in plain old A major and the sheet I found is wrong?

Comment: If you aren't sure of the key, why say `E` is the `ii` chord? If you don't know the key, you aren't ready to label function.

Comment: @Divizna - 2nd bar. With E#, followed by F nat. seems like the writer is pretty clueless, so I'd discount any credibility in the chart. True, A Mix. is the same set of notes as D maj. hence 2# key sig. However, the chords move swiftly out of diatonics, so D (or A Mix) can't work anyway. We seem to have so many questions here where OPs are under the misapprehension that a song needs to use only diatonic notes. Who's spreading that bad rumour?

Comment: @Tim So you rule that out and deem the song to belong into good old A major that should have three sharps. (Unless I'm getting you wrong.) Suspected as much. Now I'm wondering if the asker is using that very same sheet and that's where he got misled.

Comment: @Divizna - plus D#o written with Eb? And OP calling it Do? Wouldn't give it a push off the side! Said it too many times - just 'cos it's on the 'net doesn't mean it's true! Or accurate.

Comment: @Tim "Ddim" I'm willing to discount as a typo, and I mentioned that it was the only staff sheet Google turned up, so maybe getting a second opinion wasn't so readily easy for John either... but wow, Eb in a D#dim? Didn't read that far and I refuse to believe even a completely clueless human is capable of such a thing (it's right in the name!), did someone plug in an instrument and let their computer get the notes from that, no proofreading? Yeah, not believing that thing a nose between the eyes. For all I know the pitches may be right but the way they're denoted is clearly shady.

Answer (score 1):

Even though your question is incomplete I will let you know that this song is NOT in D. It is in the key of A and the D chord is the IV. That makes the E the V chord although in this progression it is just a passing chord from vi to IV. A few other things to be aware of are:

There is no sense of chord duration or timing in the way you wrote the chords.

This is only half of the progression. The second half starts out the same but ends in a G to D.

What you wrote as Ddim is actually a D#dim

There are non-diatonic chords in this progression which means that a single scale probably will sound wrong over certain chords. If you do play a single scale, A major (Ionian) will sound much better than A Mixolydian because at least it contains the G# of the C#7 chord and the G# of the E chord. Jerry Garcia improvises mostly with an A major pentatonic but he does sometimes use a few choice non-diatonic notes like an E# over the C#7 and a D# over the B7 chord. Both those notes are the 3rds of those chords and FYI they are 7th chords, not triads.

Comment: Entirely agree! One of those songs where the last chord just *isn't* a key indicator! (Maybe that's what OP thought), I really expected an E instead of D on the turn arounds, though. Because of the V/V/V/V> V/V/V>V/V> (!!!) no one scale will ever work, not even a pent. maj. +1.

Comment: @Tim It’s one of those songs that I had to listen to in order to make sense of it.(The Jerry version is cleaner than the Dead version)  In this case it has to loop back to bar 1 for the plagal cadence (D-A) resolution. This progression has some interesting elements to it.

Comment: Yes, it's just that several other songs do the V/V/V trick, ending on simple V ready for the turn around, which then sounds inevitable. Is it clever, or contrived..?